# Why won't videos be placed into my local directory instead of blank files without a file type?

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to place `.mp4` videos to my local `newVideos/` directory but I keep getting this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(2): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/name/workspace/scripts/index.php on line 21
```

I'm not sure what to fix.  I've tried changing up the first param of `file_put_contents()` to match what the warning says but to no avail.  So far, it's grabbing blank files numbered 1-13 without a file type and placing them inside `newVideos/`.

```
foreach($videoUrls as $file) {
    file_put_contents("newVideos/" . pathinfo($file) ["basename"], fopen($file, 'r')) . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($file);
}
```

This is the format of `$videoUrls` just FYI

```
array(122) {
  ["https://creatives.sascdn.com/video1.mp4"]=>
  int(7)
  ["https://creatives.sascdn.com/video2.mp4"]=>
  int(1)
  ["https://creatives.sascdn.com/video3.mp4"]=>
  int(1)
  ["https://creatives.sascdn.com/video4.mp4"]=>
)
```

Comment: Well for example I visited https://creatives.sascdn.com/video1.mp4 in my browser and got a 404 Not Found error. So probably those URLs just don't exist. The warning is telling you it couldn't find a file when it tried to open the URL using fopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$file` is an integer change your loop to

```
foreach($videoUrls as $file => $value) {
    file_put_contents("newVideos/" . pathinfo($file) ["basename"], fopen($file, 'r')) . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it works, silly mistake on my end!